# Submit button on web browser with html element

Tags: html, vb.net, web

Okay, so this website http://dogwars.com/app/

I'm making an app where you can login and stuff.

But the login button on the website:

```
<div style="margin-left: 77px; margin-top: 20px; height: 40px;">
   <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('loginForm').submit();" class="button"><span>Login</span></a>
  </div>
```

for my automatic submit button on VB.net I use this:

```
If curElement.GetAttribute("onclick").Equals("document.getElementById('loginForm').submit();") Then
            curElement.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
```

But it will not log in automatically and I'm puzzled as to why it doesn't..?

Could someone help me out?
here is my full code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://dogwars.com/app/")

End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")

    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection

        Dim controlName As String = curElement.GetAttribute("name").ToString

        If controlName = "email" Then

            curElement.SetAttribute("Value", TextBox1.Text)

        ElseIf controlName = "password" Then

            curElement.SetAttribute("Value", TextBox2.Text)

        End If

    Next


    theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
        If curElement.GetAttribute("onclick").Equals("document.getElementById('loginForm').submit();") Then
            curElement.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What do you mean you want to log in automatically

Comment: Its like an automatic login thing, where i type in my username and password and it loads the site enters the details and presses the login button for me.

Comment: How does it know when you're done typing in the password?

Comment: I type the username and password in the textboxes, when i click submit on the program, it loads the url in the webbrowser with the details i typed in the textbox's in the website, then it clicks login for me. or it should.

Comment: Do you have a valid username/password I can use to test it?

Answer (score 0):

You are over complicating things with the HTML Elements. Here's what you should do:

```
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://dogwars.com/app/")

            Do Until WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
                Application.DoEvents()
            Loop

            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email").SetAttribute("value",TextBox1.Text())
            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value",TextBox2.Text())
            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click")
```

That should probably work I haven't tested it though.